# change vbulletin mysql character encoding to latin1 on centos

Tags: mysql, encoding, centos, vbulletin, latin1

i have a problem...
we moved site from server to server...
and after that our site ascii code not working true...
if i add an ascii code to editor on vbulletin there is problem after saving post...
i saw on database.. 
&#9604 ; must be save but saving „â– 
there is a problem but how can i solve this problem..
i looked show variables ...

character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    latin1
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection    latin1_swedish_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci

but i looked on vbulletin sql query

all of them latin1...only character_set_system utf8 but i cant latin1 all of them..
how can i fix it...
please help me ...
i looked 3 months ...
sorry my bad english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: thanks but i didnt do this yet... please help me ...maybe skype etc..

Comment: Search this forum for "Mojibake".